# move files from one folder to another and if exists rename

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find a solution to move all files, all types of extensions,from source folder to destination folder.

The problem is the scripts I found online are not checking if there are already files with the same name in destination folder and if it's the case to add the underscore and a variable number(1,2,3,4,5 and so on) at the end of the file.

I have something here that I tried to put together but it's not working. Batch script or Powershell doesn't matter. The requested outcome is to move all files and if file a.pdf exists in destination folder, move it to destination folder and add a variable number a_1.pdf or a_2.pdf

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing2"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%~nxa" (
  SET notfound=Y
  FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,999) DO IF DEFINED notfound IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%~na(%%b)%%~xa" (
   (move "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~na(%%b)%%~xa"
   SET "notfound="
  )
  IF DEFINED notfound ECHO(Failed to COPY "%%a"
 ) ELSE ((move "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa"
 )
)

pause
```

actual outcome it this

```
move "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing\1.jpeg" "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing2\1(1).jpeg"
move "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing\1.txt" "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing2\1(1).txt"
```

but when I look in the folder, nothing happens

Many thanks

Comment: _"it's not working"_ isn't a helpful problem description. What is the actual outcome and what is the expected outcome? Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: i have updated the outcome

Comment: `ECHO(move` merely `echo`es the `move` command. This is so that the commands that are proposed to be run can be examined for sanity. If you want to actually *run* the `move` then change `ECHO(move` to `move` (there are two instances in your batch)

Comment: Magoo yes of course but the code is doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testing2"

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%~nxa" (
  rem destfile exists
  echo destfile "%destdir%\%%~nxa" exists
  SET "notfound=Y"
  FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,999) DO IF DEFINED notfound IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%~na(%%b)%%~xa" (
   move "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~na(%%b)%%~xa"
   SET "notfound="
  )
  IF DEFINED notfound ECHO Failed to COPY "%%a"
 ) ELSE (
  rem destfile does not exist
  echo destfile "%destdir%\%%~nxa" does NOT EXIST
  move "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa" >nul
 )
)
GOTO :eof
```

This worked for me. Frankly, I'm too tired to work out the differences.

Notes : 
I overrode the directoryname values.
I added rems and step-by-step reporting, which obviously could be removed
Caution : code executes `move` statements as posted.